# How to inject NavigationManager in bunit Blazor component unit test

Tags: c#, blazor, xunit, blazor-server-side, bunit

I am getting this error when injecting from unit test.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ''NavigationManagerProxy' has not been initialized.'
```

My code:

```
Services.AddSingleton<NavigationManager>(Mock.Of<NavigationManager>());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use this class for my unit tests:

```
internal class TestNav : NavigationManager
{
    public TestNav()
    {
        Initialize("https://unit-test.example/", "https://unit-test.example/");
    }

    protected override void NavigateToCore(string uri, bool forceLoad)
    {
        NotifyLocationChanged(false);
    }
}
```

Then inside the test set it up like this:

```
Services.AddSingleton<NavigationManager>(new TestNav());
```

Comment: I get an error "The name 'Services' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 2):

While writing tests for the [Blazing Pizza Workshop](https://github.com/egil/blazor-workshop), we used this (similar to @Akinzekeel's code):

```
    public class FakeNavigationManager : NavigationManager
    {
        private readonly ITestRenderer renderer;

        public FakeNavigationManager(ITestRenderer renderer)
        {
            Initialize("http://localhost/", "http://localhost/");
            this.renderer = renderer;
        }

        protected override void NavigateToCore(string uri, bool forceLoad)
        {
            Uri = ToAbsoluteUri(uri).ToString();

            renderer.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
                () => NotifyLocationChanged(isInterceptedLink: false));
        }
    }
```

and the tests look like this:

```
@inherits TestContext
@code {
    private NavigationManager navigationManager; 

    public MainLayoutTests()
    {
        Services.AddSingleton<NavigationManager, FakeNavigationManager>();
        navigationManager = Services.GetService<NavigationManager>();        
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyOrdersNavigationItem_Is_Marked_As_Active_When_Viewing_MyOrdersPage()
    {
        var cut = Render(@<MainLayout />);

        navigationManager.NavigateTo("myorders");

        cut.Find("a[href=myorders]")
            .ClassList
            .Should()
            .Contain("active");
    }
}
```

I haven't tested all sorts of scenarios, but this seems to work in this case at least.

Answer (score 2):

bUnit [fakes NavigationManager automatically](https://bunit.dev/docs/test-doubles/fake-navigation-manager.html) and registers it with the test context services so to verify navigation you can fetch the bUnit fake and check the url:

```
var navMan = ctx.Services.GetRequiredService<FakeNavigationManager>();
Assert.Equal("http://localhost/foo", navMan.Uri);
```

or if you want to trigger navigation:

```
navMan.NavigateTo("newUrl");
```